# How to use Laravel auth() in a Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I normally was using Auth in Laravel blade view to remove buttons that some users have no right too. Now i have just started lately trying to learn Vue and im wondering how im supposed to use this in a Vue Component.

This is what i were using in blade and would like to use in Vue component.

```
    @if(!Auth::guest() && ($post->author_id == Auth::user()->id))
        <a href="{{ url('home/edit/'.$post->slug)}}" class="btn-sm btn-info">Edit Post</a>
        <a href="{{  url('home/delete/'.$post->id.'?_token='.csrf_token()) }}" class="btn-sm btn-warning">Delete</a>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the User instance into the component with a prop. For example:

```
<example-component :user="{{ Auth::user() }}"></example-component>
```

Then you can access the user's information like so:

```
<template>

 <p>{{ user.name }}</p>

</template>
export default {
   props : ['user']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for using default Laravel Auth. You should use special packages for API authentication such as Laravel Sanctum https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum